# Can I get all records from one speciefic field with single command?

Tags: delphi, tadoquery

I have a database *.mdb. The task is to get all the values from a certain field of this database and write them to a file.
Now the code looks something like this

```
while not ADOQuery1.Eof do begin
   resultstringlist.add(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('_fieldname_').asString);
   ADOQuery1.next;
end;
```

It works, but I think that there is a more optimal and faster option. With a database size of about 40,000 records, this process takes quite a long time. Database which I need to work with contains dozens of times more records and dozens of tables.
I think this is a pretty stupid question, but I could not find a solution in a few days myself. Databases for me is an unexplored territory. Not for long, I hope.

Comment: What does your SQL query look like? Do you have an index on the field you are querying?

Comment: Why are you retrieving 40K (or more) records in the first place? There's no way you can be usefully displaying that to the user in a listbox or combobox. Sounds like you should be rethinking both your application logic and SQL statements to me. In addition, you're spending a lot of time reallocating memory for the stringlist, because it has to keep growing and growing and growing, which also consumes a lot of time (and can fragment memory pretty badly).

Comment: I can create a new database with a few fields I need to work with.
It will have about 20-50 fields, but all the same 40,000 records
It's not usual exchange of client-server or client-client. This is a database with accumulated experimental data for few days, which I need to work with. Construct graphs, interpolate, evaluate the correlation between different fields, etc. 
The first field in each record is a point along the X axis (datetime format). The remaining fields are points along the Y axis (real or integer format).
I can't take just a hundred points and work only with them.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `FieldByName` in a tight loop, it does a linear search through the dataset's `Fields` on each call.  Instead, look up the field before the loop and assign the result to a TField local variable and access the field value in the loop using that variable.  So, use something like

```
var AField : TField;
...
AField := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('_fieldname_');

ADOQuery1.DisableControls;
try
  while not ADOQuery1.Eof do begin
    resultstringlist.add(AField.asString);
   ADOQuery1.next;
  end;
finally
  ADOQuery1.EnableControls;
end;
```

The calls to `DisableControls` and `EnableControls` avoid the loop being slowed down by updating any db-aware gui controls connected to the AdoQuery.

You might also get into the habit of calling `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` on any TStrings-descended objects while updating them in a tight loop.

Comment: True. Maybe iterating internal `Recordset` can bring even more joy :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you
I will try it soon and let you know how much this solution will speed up the calculations.